# How to use a Windows DLL with Java in Mac OS X?

Tags: java, c, macos, dll, java-native-interface

I have seen some Java projects using `taucs.dll`, [TAUCS](http://www.tau.ac.il/~stoledo/taucs/)—a C library of sparse linear solvers, through JNI in Windows. I guess I can achieve the same in Mac OS X by compiling TAUCS into something like `libTaucs.jnilib`. I have access to the library's code but no idea how to compile it into a DLL, let alone a JNI library. So far I can compile only to a static library.

Is there a way to convert a DLL to a JNI library for Mac? If I have to compile the code, how to do so? Will wrapping a static library in a dynamic library work with JNI, especially for TAUCS if anyone has an experience?

Answer (score 8):

Finally Microsoft released [.NET Core](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos) which is completely platform independent. When you build a DLL using .NET Core framework you can run the file with following command.

```
dotnet yourapp.dll
```

Also, now .NET applications can be developed on Mac or Linux machine using the lightweight IDE [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) and [Visual Studio for Mac](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-mac/) IDE has been released where [Mono on MacOS X](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/) is integrated.