# NoClassDefFound error because of System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, opencv

I am trying to *use opencv 2.4.9. with maven*, i have two files - the first one is  a java file which is in a maven project , and the second one is a java file with all the opencv imports  but this file is in the same package, am calling a function of second java file from the first one. 
The two files run fine separately as java project but when I try to run the complete maven project it throws this error - 
**(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core)**

and the build fails.

After a lot of research i found out that the problem is mostly because of
**System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);**
which am using to load opencv libraries.
To rectify this, there are solutions to add *opencv.dll* to the java folder but since am working *os x 10.9.5*, i dont have dll's as they are found in the build folder under opencv, but build folder will only be there if we have installed opencv, and i cannot find a .dmg file for opencv. What should i do?

PS: This is my first post on SO.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of hit and trials, directly specifying the path of the opencv.dll in the **System.loadLibrary("Complete Path to opencv.dll")** seems to have done the trick, but in Mac the problem remains as it is as I do not have any .dll or .so or .dylib for opencv in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never used opencv:

There is a Mac OS X download from opencv

- https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.0.0-beta.zip
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-unix/2.4.10/opencv-2.4.10.zip/download

I suppose there should be an opencv.dll equivalent native library (opencv.jnilib?) in the opencv package for Mac OS X and loading it with System.loadLibrary could resolve the issue.

There is a article how to load a native library on Mac OS X.

- http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-MacOSX.asp

---

May be relevant:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/A3cL3dkD70I
- http://answers.opencv.org/question/7958/no-opencv_java244-in-javalibrarypath/
- http://answers.opencv.org/question/8415/opencv-244-on-mac-os-x-with-eclipse/

Comment: Quick search showed opencv.jnilib such as https://github.com/Tkres/DC32_MConvo/tree/master/libraries/OpenCV (not sure this is safe one, so please make sure).

Comment: Hey ! thanks for the answer and i followed all the steps given in that tutorial but after finishing each step i got this :
(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Library/Java/Extensions/libOpenCV.jnilib: dlopen(/Library/Java/Extensions/libOpenCV.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Java/Extensions/libOpenCV.jnilib: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x0A 0x0A 0x0A 0x0A 0x3C 0x21 0x44 0x4F)

It seems .jnilib is not recognisable. I hope you can help.

Comment: Apart from it, am not able to understand what the 4th step is for?
And how exactly do i use it?

Comment: Not sure how the code was written, where the library is placed, from where the library was acquired, so it is a bit difficult to understand the situation… If the code was like System.loadLibrary("libOpenCV.jnilib"), the suffix part .jnlib should not be specified, I suppose. Anyway, needs more details in a way other people may be able to reproduce the issue...

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but without answer yet. For me that solve the problem for System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME): https://stackoverflow.com/a/35112123

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? Could you elaborate? Do you mean the linked Stack Overflow question solved a similar problem for you?

Comment: On Windows you can specify the path for dll, on MAC you don't have it. So, to fix the error when use System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME) in MAC I download and compile the opencv using brew install opencv3 --with-java --with-python3. It will be installed in /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/XXX/share/OpenCV/java
Link libopencv_javaXXX.so to libopencv_javaXXX.dylib:
ln -s libopencv_javaXXX.so libopencv_javaXXX.dylib
Now add /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/XXX/share/OpenCV/java as Native

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu Linux, I got the similar problem which can't find the native library which actually is the libopencv_javaxxx.so (xxx is the version)
which is actually installed under /usr/lib/jni/ not like other native libraries installed under /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

My first thought for the native library is the libopencv_core.so and there is no libopencv.so at all.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[Unsupported platform in nu.pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48517692/nu-pattern-opencvunsupportedplatformexception-operating-system-windows-and-a) and my suggested answer to [openCV Java on Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821793/using-javacv-with-kotlin/56793806#56793806) which shows how to use the `nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadShared();` API.