# jar exception with opencv

Tags: java, opencv

i have problem with java while using opencv , everything Works fine but when i Create a jar file and execute it , i got Error .
    C:\User\Asus>java -jar "virus.jar" .
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at virus.Virus.(Virus.java:75)

Comment: Check my answer..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581404/java-programming-opencv-unsatisfied-link-error/56320367#56320367

Comment: You could also see [My answer to Java/Kotlin/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821793/using-javacv-with-kotlin/56793806#56793806) which uses . `nu.pattern` api/

Answer (score 0):

so i fixed the probleme using cmd here is the instruction :
C:\Users\asus>java -Djava.library.path="C:\opencv3\opencv\build\java\x64" -jar "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\jar export\trojanexe.jar".
for more information about java.library.path visite this site : https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadlibrary-windows.asp