# Why changing name of jar causes UnsatisfiedLinkError exception

Tags: java, dll, jar, java-native-interface

### Why does same jar contents with name **shaded.jar** fail to load dll while with name **sigar.jar** , dlls load successfully?

I am using shaded jar in maven.It creates a jar: **shaded.jar**.

I have an artifact :

```
<dependency>

        <groupId>org.hyperic</groupId>

        <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>

        <version>1.6.5.132-7</version>

    </dependency
```

I use it in my code like:

```
SigarProxyCache.newInstance(new Sigar(), 100).getPid();
```

Since this jar uses dll, I have kept all the dlls in the same folder as **shaded.jar**, but still i get following exception:

> Caused by: org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException:
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getPid()J     at
>   org.hyperic.sigar.SigarProxyCache.invoke(SigarProxyCache.java:220)
>     ... 2 more

If I add sigar.jar *(same version that has been added to shaded.jar)* to classpath directly instead of packaging it in **shaded .jar**, no exception is thrown and dll is loaded successfully. (Since jar and lib are in same folder, there wasn't any need to modify the `java.library.path`)

**Furthermore, even if I remove sigar.jar from classpath and rename my shaded.jar(this one contains sigar packaged) to sigar.jar, dll loading is still successful.**

Now I have referred following posts:

[Extract and load DLL from JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar)

[UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java249 in java.library.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088934/unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-opencv-java249-in-java-library-path)

which suggest a solution but my question is, why does changing the name impact dll loading. Since inside **shaded.jar** as well ass **sigar.jar**, the package structure is exactly same and in both cases dlls are lying parallel to jar.

Here is list of dll/so files that sigar.jar needs,  they all contain **sigar** in their name:
[image]

Comment: Maybe someone thought it would be clever to derive the DLL name from the name of the jar

Comment: Are you guessing or this is how it works?

Comment: Guessing, of course. Because that's not how it usually works. Also putting the lib in the same directory as the jar doesn't usually make a difference. If it does for you, that means someone has written extra code to find the lib. You could try renaming the lib too

Comment: Yes, I tried renaming the lib by replacing 'sigar' with 'shaded', it doesn't work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was curious. Had a look at the code at github. To find the name of the native library they take the class name, search the classpath for a jar file with the same name then look in the directory where it's found. When you put the classes in a file with another name, the jar isn't found, so the same-directory approach fails.