# Is it possible to use DLLs with Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I have an application that uses a third party DLL. Is there a way in Visual Studio for Mac to write an application to access it the same way as I can on windows?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Visual Studio for Mac isn't going to suddenly make it possible to natively execute Windows binaries on the Macintosh. So...unless I'm misunderstanding your question, no.

Comment: You should contact the third party and ask for a Mac version of their library.

Comment: I can't verify it, but it seems likely that .NET core/standard DLLs would work

Comment: The source code of the DLL is available, written in C (http://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/). Since VS-Mac is based on Mono and Xamarin as far as I know, it seems that there could be a potential that this could happen.

Comment: @CodyGray isn't that precisely what something like Ionic does for JAVA and web languages? I don't think that's outside the scope of possibility at all.

Comment: No. It doesn't make *Windows binaries* execute on the Macintosh or any other platform. You would need a compiler that generated native Macintosh-compatible binaries. Microsoft doesn't make one. @spark

Comment: @Cody, Ah, so it's a  waaaaay lower level issue. Yeah, that doesn't seem like an issue that'll be tackled.

Answer (score 7):

It depends:

1. Managed .NET DLL:
   Can be imported and used the same way as in VS on Windows
2. Native DLL: can't be used directly. You'll need to build it for your target system, OSX in your case.

If you have C/C++ code you should be able to build it for OSX (with GCC for example) if it doesn't have some foreign (Windows) platform specific code. Then you can use the compiled *.so / *.dylib file directly. But you'll need to tell the .NET Runtime (Mono for example on OSX) to use the different file using a DllMap configuration file (see http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/dllmap/ for examples).

The sources you've linked look like they're for Unix, so the chance to be able to build them on OSX are pretty good (there's a Makefile and the resulting binary would be libswe.so on Unix). You could try to pass the `-dynamiclib` parameter to GCC to get a OSX specific libswe.dylib ([What are the differences between .so and .dylib on osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339679/what-are-the-differences-between-so-and-dylib-on-osx) seems to be a good answer about dylib)

If you have the binary of your DLL for OSX, you just need a configuration file for your .NET application, which could look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap os="osx" dll="libswe.dll" target="libswe.dylib"/>
<configuration/>
```

It tells the .NET Runtime to import the symbols from `libswe.dylib` instead of `libswe.dll` if the current OS is OSX.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Although you might think that because you have an IDE with the same name as the Windows counterpart the binaries it produces are not transferable.

An [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/228309/macos-dll-equivalent) gives some more information:

> There's no real DLLs in OS X, Linux, or any POSIX for that matter.
>   They don't make the differentiation.
>
> Why?
>
> A lot of Mac stuff, for one, is self-contained (.app's are really just
>   folders after all).

**Although...**

[Another queston on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901438/how-to-use-a-windows-dll-with-java-in-mac-os-x) asks the same thing, and an answer says:

> Finally Microsoft released .NET Core which is completely platform
>   independent.
>
> ... now .NET applications can be developed on Mac or Linux machine
>   using the lightweight IDE Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio for Mac
>   IDE has been released where Mono on MacOS X is integrated.

So if the supplier of the library (DLL) you want to use has created a version of it with the .NET Core framework, you might be in luck.